# How to select columns of a numpy matrix based on a 1-D boolean mask?

Tags: python, numpy

Let us consider the matrix `A`

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

We want to identify and remove all the columns where each element is 0. We can generate a mask such as

```
mask = np.all(A == 0, axis=0)
# output: [False, True, False, True, True, False]
```

How do I use `mask` (or `~mask`) to create a copy of `A` where only the non-null columns are kept? That is

```
[[1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]])

>>> mask = np.all(A == 0, axis=0)
>>> mask
array([False,  True, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

>>> A[:,mask]
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

>>> A[:,~mask]
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1]])
```